# How do I return .POST() data from jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm trying to have a php file echo the POST values sent to it - not having much luck.

Javascript:

```
$(".loginform").submit(function () {

    if ($(this).attr('rel') == "login") {

        $(this).attr('rel', 'loggedin')
        var $el = $(this);

        $.post("init.php", {name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function (data) {
            $el.after(data);
        })
    }

    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
if($_POST["name"]){echo $_POST["name"];}; //WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK?
```

I have a feeling I'm not quite understand the type of data being passed. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I change .post to the below, still not working.

```
$(".loginform").submit(function(){

    if($(this).attr('rel') == "login"){
        $(this).attr('rel', 'loggedin'); 
        var $el = $(this); 
        $.ajax({
            data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
            url: "init.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        }); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

You can try the code by going to http://thinkcloud.ly. Click 'login' then 'submit.' The 'login' uses .GET, so I know that works.

Comment: Make sure you're not getting Javascript syntax errors.  You're missing semicolons after lines 4 and 8.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out - it actually runs ok (other javascript), so I know it works fine, plus my dev tools aren't returning errors.

Comment: @Jared Does the answers below solve your issue?

Comment: So far they haven't - I tried the answer from @orolo, but didn't get anything. The answer you provided isn't it as well, since I used the same code in another spot (using .get instead of .post) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem persists here:

```
$el.after(data);
```

You need to wrap them with an element, try doing this:

```
$el.after('<span>' + data + '</span>');
```

If this doesn't work, could you confirm what you see with `alert(data)`?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
print_r( $_POST );
print_r( $_REQUEST  );
```

to look at scope.

&& same  with var_dump
It can be json encoded data sometimes, use json_* php functions so ... for decode it first.

BTW, firebug can show all passed variables.

Also .post in jquery have 4'd param (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
datatype.  dataTypeThe type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html).

Am using json ... so php script must make something like echo(json_encode($arr)) to return this to .post call.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple missing `;` in your javascript

Once you have your javascript straightened out the next step is to make sure that the data is actually being passed. Install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). With this you can see exactly what is being sent to `init.php`.  This way you know where the error is occurring.

For example... with firebug you would've known that the javascript wasn't firing correctly and could've spotted the errors.

Comment: The code runs fine without the semicolons, I tested it before running jsbeautifier

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure you set the datatype and you may want to use $.ajax until you get it working:

```
$.ajax({
   data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   url: "init.php",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
       alert(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: Glad to see you're using an alert to verify the data; with datatype JSON, he can't do what he originally wants and append it to the document directly.

Comment: why .ajax instead of .post?

Comment: Sam Creamer, yes, should use post.